# 'The method join isn't defined' error in Flutter SQFlite package and 'The named parameter 'id' isn't defined' error in Flutter SQLite

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite

I am making a flutter app using SQLite for storage.

I have used [SQflite package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) for using SQLite.

Here's the file in which I've written all the CRUD functions (I have included comments to indicate where is the error in the file):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'Employee.dart';

class DBmanager {
  late Database _database;

  Future openDb() async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await openDatabase(
          join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'medicine.db'),//getting an error in this line for the join keyword
          version: 1, onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE Employee(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, medicineName TEXT, Frequency TEXT, dosageAmount TEXT, medicineType TEXT, instructions TEXT)',
        );
      });
    }
  }

  //function to insert medicine in the database
  Future<int> insertMedicine(Medicine medicine) async {
    await openDb();
    return await _database.insert('Medicine', medicine.toMap());
  }

  //function to get information of medicine from database
  Future<List<Medicine>> getMedicineList() async {
    await openDb();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await _database.query('Medicine');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Medicine(
        id: maps[i]['id'],//getting error in this line for 'id'
        medicineName: maps[i]['Medicine name'],
        frequency: maps[i]['Frequency'],
        dosageAmount: maps[i]['Dosage Amount'],
        medicineType: maps[i]['Medicine Type'],
        instructions: maps[i]['Instructions'],
      );
    });
  }

  //function to update the information of medicine in the database
  Future<int> updateMedicine(Medicine medicine) async {
    await openDb();
    return await _database.update('Medicine', medicine.toMap(),
        where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [medicine.id]);
  }

  //function to delete medicine from database
  Future<void> deleteMedicine(int id) async {
    await openDb();
    await _database.delete('Medicine', where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
  }
}
```

In the above code I am getting the follwoing errors :-
Line 12 : The method 'join' isn't defined for the type 'DBmanager'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method or defining a method named 'join'.

Line 37 : The named parameter 'id' isn't defined.
Try correcting the nameto an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'id'.

Here's the file in which I've created the medicine class:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Medicine {
  int id;
  String medicineName;
  String frequency;
  String dosageAmount;
  String medicineType;
  String instructions;

  Medicine({
    this.id,//getting an error in this line for id
    required this.medicineName,
    required this.frequency,
    required this.dosageAmount,
    required this.medicineType,
    required this.instructions,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'Medicine name': medicineName,
      'Frequency': frequency,
      'dosage Amount': dosageAmount,
      'Medicine Type': medicineType,
      'Instructions': instructions
    };
  }
}
```

In the above code I am getting the follwoing errors :-
Line 24 : The parameter 'id' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

I can't use 'required' modifier because the value of id will not be given by the user, it'll be auto-incremented.

I also tried initializing the 'id' but that didn't resolve the error.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import `path` to get `join` method.

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart';
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Can you please tell me the solution for the other two errors?

Comment: For `Medicine`'s  `id` isnt nullable, therefore you need to add `required` on constructor, also you can provide default value `this.id=0` or make it nullable `int? id;`